# Ask A Traveller - Call for Volunteers / Topics

Tags: discussion, events, chat

It was suggested in the chat that we try a chat even like Reddit, where we have an AMA event in the chat room.

What's an AMA? It comes from Reddit, where someone (even Obama!) will log in and say something like "I'm the POTUS, AMA" and then the questions start, and he responds.

After some discussion it was suggested we may get a better response and answers with topics and 'ask a traveller' events - any travellers can be in the chat room to discuss and ask/answer questions on the topic.

So anyone with an interesting topic to have questions on? Hypothetical Examples:

- Ever paid a bribe?
- Long term backpacking
- Working while travelling

Don't ask the questions here, just suggest that you'd like to be in, and your topic, and then I'll look at scheduling the events.

Comment: (off-topic/non-constructive comments removed, feel free to continue discussion in the chat)

Comment: What are the criteria to appear as a guest on the show?

Answer (score 4):

**Travelling with small children**

Ever wondered what your travelling life is going to be like once you got kids? Curious about taking strollers and car seats with you on a plane? Or are you wondering about good gear for hiking with kids who can barely walk?

Ask a parent.

Comment: +1 Even though I (fortunately) don't have any kids, I always wanted to know more about this topic ;)

Comment: In the meantime, check out http://www.discovershareinspire.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what AMA is or what kind of format it is, never the less, some thoughts on topics:

**Worst traveling experience.** We all have some terrible stuff in our baggage, may it be being mugged, seeing something unpleasant, a terrible hostel/hotel, being lied to (more than usual) or too high expectations. I am thinking anyone participating in such a discussion will either be new to the situation and can learn from what's told Or they will find themselves remember the exact same thing and can contribute. I know I would Love to have someone talk to me about their "in general" bad experiences when traveling to certain destinations, when an experienced traveler tells you they had a bad experience it is probably true.

**Best traveling experience, so far.** The exact opposite to the above. Single out some fantastic stuff, maybe there are even several of us to agree on some things, a good conversation to reference when someone asks about this sort of thing. And god knows people ask! An epic saga of awesome adventures from different peoples perspective woooo :D

**Making money will on the go.** Can it be done, are there people doing it.

**Traveling insurance, what you haven't got it????** Not sure how to put this, but the whole insurance thing, most of the more seasoned travelers are rather care free people I believe. And generally don't fall for simple adds, but I feel this should be discussed, especially since it varies greatly between people you talk to. Again could well be a great discussion to reference in the future.

All the above topics (and subsequent discussions, including the traveling with children suggestion posted before) could be used as **foundation for blog posts** on the same subjects on the blog. Whenever we do get out of Beta. I could reference people there, people that doesn't have a specific question to ask in the Q&A format, just family and friends wondering things. I don't know how many times people ask me about traveling insurance. The discussion would then provide a foundation with many views on which a blog post would be great i think.

You guys will have to steer me in the right direction if this doesn't work for whatever AMA is. (Ask My Answer?)

**EDITs:** Oh and also, I'd be happy to share my traveling experiences :D

Oh and also also, maybe some topics should be in a kind of non-realtime, I mean send a mail to the traveler asking some specific questions or just statements, and the traveler can then have some time to answer. This again would be more as a foundation for future blog posts, and probably not at all in line with AMA. In fact maybe this should be in another post all together.. Oh well. Sort it later when the comments start coming in.

*Oh and also also also, I love this whole idea btw. Just as a side note.*

Comment: AMA == Ask Me Anything. I do like the "Make money on the go" topic, it's going to be very interesting to die-hard travellers.

Comment: Ah, well, I wasn't that far off then :D Thanks @mindcorrosive. And yes, the beauty of this kind of thing would be to get the experiences from multiple people. Asking several travelers. :D *When I think about it doesn't topics eliminate the AMA format, since it isn't "anything" anymore? Just a thought heh*